# Flask structure -- can't import application from __init__.py

Tags: python, flask

I'm a beginner with python and I've been having a lot of trouble setting up the structure of my applications using `__init__.py` even after searching through several tutorials.

At the moment, my current directory structure looks like the following

```
/parent
   /myapp
       __init__.py
       views.py
   /virtualenv
```

Previously, I had (if it makes any difference)

```
/parent
   /myapp
   /bin
   /include
   /lib
```

The contents of `__init__.py` are below:

```
 from flask import Flask
 app = Flask(__name__)
```

and my views.py

```
 from myapp import app
 @app.route('/')
 def test():
    return 'This is a new test'

 if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

If `myapp` is being initialized with the init file, why can't I call it into the views? I get an error stating 'I cannot import app and I have no module named myapp'. If I remove the init file and copy the contents into the top of the views.py file, everything works fine.

Comment: you might also want to consider following an "application factory" pattern for what you're trying to do. [fbone](https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone/blob/master/fbone/app.py) has a great example of it. If you want something simpler here's what I tend to use. https://github.com/DarkCrowz/innovation_center/blob/master/innovation_center/app/__init__.py

Comment: @corvid the DarkCrowz link is dead, can you find and update it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are using `views` as the main script. You cannot put a script inside a package; the directory it is in cannot be treated as such. Python adds the `parent/myapp` directory to the Python path, not the `parent` path.

Add a *separate* script at the top level (next to `myapp`):

```
from myapp import app

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

and add an import to `__init__.py` to import your views:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

import views
```

and remove the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block from `views.py`.