# Python2.7(flask) reference to import variable from ___init___.py inside module

Tags: python, module, flask, package

I need to import a variable that is initialized in the `__init__.py` of my package.

```
======__init__.py======
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager


basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blah'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'thermos.db')
app.config['DEBUG'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

app.config['DEBUG'] = True

import models
import views
```

Then in my views.py and my models.py I am trying to import db and app like so:

```
===== views.py ====
from thermos import app, db
```

This is not working as I would expect.  At the moment my directory structure looks like this:

```
/thermos
   /thermos
      __init__.py
      views.py
      models.py
```

The tutorial I am using uses the exact setup I have listed above, however it does not work for me.  To get the code to work I have to make the following changes:

```
===== views.py ====
from . import app, db

===== models.py ====
from . import db
```

Why isn't it working for me? Is my change acceptable? I don't like to use relative links. Halp? Thanks!

The error in question:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
    from thermos import app
  File "/home/python/projects/plural_flask/thermos/thermos/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    import models
  File "/home/python/projects/plural_flask/thermos/thermos/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    from thermos import db
ImportError: cannot import name db
```

I have already read these:
[Flask structure -- can't import application from __init__.py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24589147/flask-structure-cant-import-application-from-init-py)
[Python: How to import from an __init__.py file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22282316/python-how-to-import-from-an-init-py-file)

and many others, but still can't figure out why it works for the tutorial I'm following and not on my own machine with the same setup.

Comment: Read about circular imports in Python.

Comment: I'm using flask and this exact build structure is actually referenced in the tutorial, here ( http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/packages/ ) at the bottom.  It even has a circular imports section.

I just don't understand why, in their code, it says **import yourapplication.views** but in my code **import views** only works. Also, they have it just like the tutorial I'm following: **from yourapplication import app**, but in my code only **from . import app** works.  Everything is setup the same as far as I can tell.  Why is it throwing an error for me?

Answer (score 0):

My answer comes from another stackoverflow answer: [Python circular importing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22187279/python-circular-importing)

Essentially use `import db`  rather than `from thermos import db`